# can't get tf.train.shuffle_batch() work properly

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've been working the whole day on this and I don't think another would make a difference !

I have an`.png` file, from which I've made >400 copies`[ I got to use images with different shapes, but for now I just want to get this starting ]`

here the code I use hopping to images as Tensors with the labels:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import numpy
batch_Size =20
num_epochs = 100
files = os.listdir("Test_PNG")
files = ["Test_PNG/" + s for s in files]
files = [os.path.abspath(s) for s in files ]


def read_my_png_files( filename_queue):
    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    imgName,imgTensor = reader.read(filename_queue)
    img =  tf.image.decode_png(imgTensor,channels=0)
    # Processing should be add
    return img,imgName

def inputPipeline(filenames, batch_Size, num_epochs= None):
    filename_queue  = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames, num_epochs=num_epochs,shuffle =True)
    img_file, label = read_my_png_files(filename_queue)
    min_after_dequeue = 100
    capacity = min_after_dequeue+3*batch_Size
    img_batch,label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([img_file,label],batch_size=batch_Size,enqueue_many=True,
                                                    allow_smaller_final_batch=True, capacity=capacity,
                                                    min_after_dequeue =min_after_dequeue, shapes=[w,h,d])
    return img_batch,label_batch

images, Labels  = inputPipeline(files,batch_Size,num_epochs)
```

Based on what I've understand  I should get `20` times images as tensors and their labels. 
when I run the code bellow here is what I've get:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-08857195e465> in <module>()
     34     return img_batch,label_batch
     35 
---> 36 images, Labels  = inputPipeline(files,batch_Size,num_epochs)

<ipython-input-3-08857195e465> in inputPipeline(filenames, batch_Size, num_epochs)
     31     img_batch,label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([img_file,label],batch_size=batch_Size,enqueue_many=True,
     32                                                     allow_smaller_final_batch=True, capacity=capacity,
---> 33                                                     min_after_dequeue =min_after_dequeue, shapes=[w,h,d])
     34     return img_batch,label_batch
     35 

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py in shuffle_batch(tensors, batch_size, capacity, min_after_dequeue, num_threads, seed, enqueue_many, shapes, allow_smaller_final_batch, shared_name, name)
   1212       allow_smaller_final_batch=allow_smaller_final_batch,
   1213       shared_name=shared_name,
-> 1214       name=name)
   1215 
   1216 

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\training\input.py in _shuffle_batch(tensors, batch_size, capacity, min_after_dequeue, keep_input, num_threads, seed, enqueue_many, shapes, allow_smaller_final_batch, shared_name, name)
    767     queue = data_flow_ops.RandomShuffleQueue(
    768         capacity=capacity, min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue, seed=seed,
--> 769         dtypes=types, shapes=shapes, shared_name=shared_name)
    770     _enqueue(queue, tensor_list, num_threads, enqueue_many, keep_input)
    771     full = (math_ops.cast(math_ops.maximum(0, queue.size() - min_after_dequeue),

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\data_flow_ops.py in __init__(self, capacity, min_after_dequeue, dtypes, shapes, names, seed, shared_name, name)
    626         shared_name=shared_name, name=name)
    627 
--> 628     super(RandomShuffleQueue, self).__init__(dtypes, shapes, names, queue_ref)
    629 
    630 

c:\users\engine\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\data_flow_ops.py in __init__(self, dtypes, shapes, names, queue_ref)
    151     if shapes is not None:
    152       if len(shapes) != len(dtypes):
--> 153         raise ValueError("Queue shapes must have the same length as dtypes")
    154       self._shapes = [tensor_shape.TensorShape(s) for s in shapes]
    155     else:

ValueError: Queue shapes must have the same length as dtypes
```

I declared the shape bellow to use in `tf.train.shuffle_batch` function but I still have a shape error!

Any idea how may solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue was both from

- the `enqueue_many=True` argument,
- the shape of the `shapes` argument where the `label` dimension was not there.

So I would try with `enqueue_many=False` and `shapes=[[h, w, c], []])`.

Indeed, if you look at the `shuffle_batch` doc:

> If `enqueue_many` is `False`, `tensors` is assumed to represent a
>     single example.  An input tensor with shape `[x, y, z]` will be output
>     as a tensor with shape `[batch_size, x, y, z]`.
>
> If `enqueue_many` is `True`, `tensors` is assumed to represent a
>     batch of examples, where the first dimension is indexed by example,
>     and all members of `tensors` should have the same size in the
>     first dimension.  If an input tensor has shape `[*, x, y, z]`, the
>     output will have shape `[batch_size, x, y, z]`.

But in your code, it seems you dequeue only one single file:
`img_file, label = read_my_png_files(filename_queue)` and you pass it straight to the `shuffle_batch` function:
`img_batch,label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch([img_file,label], ...)`
 so the `*` dimension is missing and TensorFlow is expecting that the first dimension of `[img_file,label]` is the number of examples.

Also bear in mind that the `enqueue_many` and the `dequeue_many` are independent; i.e.

- `*`: the number of examples you queue into the queue, is independent of
- `batch_size`: The new batch size pulled from the queue.

Comment: thanks for replying the default value for enqueue_many is false I've set it True since the Batch will have  a shape of batchSize time png shape?  anyway  it didn't work neither ways !

Comment: did you try it ? I'm u can use any png file you have !

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, it's working now , but I set have an issue understand the mechanics behind it.  tf.train.shuffle_batch([img_file,label].. ) tell the batch function which queue should it use to get the file and their labels, and the parameter batchSize tell the function how many elements  it should dequeue , right?

Comment: That's right. It makes the batch relying on the (filename) queue via the dequeue operation hidden in `imgName, imgTensor = reader.read(filename_queue)`.
The parameter `batchSize` tells the function how many elements it should dequeue from the *hidden* data queue inside `tf.train.shuffle_batch`.
There are really 2 queues: the filename and the data queue.